# Redirect Multiple Site Addresses/Labels (Including IP) to a Specific Site/Label in Caddyfile

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I have a server running `Caddy` that can be reached under the domain `rv2680.1blu.de` and `marleneschulz.info`. Both DNS A records point to the IP address `178.254.7.175`. I want to make sure `Caddy` always redirects the user to `https://marleneschulz.info`.

Here is my working `Caddyfile` :

```
www.marleneschulz.info {
    redir https://marleneschulz.info
}

https://marleneschulz.info {
    root /app/marlene/shared

    proxy / django_prod:5000 {
        header_upstream Host {host}
        header_upstream X-Real-IP {remote}
        header_upstream X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}

        except /static
    }

    log stdout
    errors stdout
    gzip
}
```

How can I prevent `Caddy` responding with e.g. `404 Site rv2680.1blu.de is not served on this interface` by explicitly defining to redirect every request from `rv2680.1blu.de:80`, `rv2680.1blu.de:443`, `178.254.7.175:80`, `178.254.7.175:443` and `marleneschulz.info` to `https://marleneschulz.info`?

I am also a bit confused since the [docs](https://caddyserver.com/docs/http-caddyfile) state nothing about the `www.` prefix.
I want to be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a couple catch-all sites and redirect them:

```
http://, https:// {
    redir https://marleneschulz.info{uri}
}
```

(I added `{uri}` because I assume you want to preserve the URI in the redirect.)

Using `http://, https://` as site addresses is the same as using `:80, :443`.

There's nothing special about the `www` prefix, either. If you wanted to enumerate all the sites you want to redirect, you would specify `www.marleneschulz.info` as one of them, just as with any other sites.